# Prevent iOS focus modes from sending calls to voicemail

Tags: iphone, ios, focus

When I turn on a Focus Mode on iOS 16, I am able to choose to not receive calls with that Focus Mode enabled. However, I noticed that the focus mode does not just silence the call; it also sends the call directly to voicemail.

Is it possible to make the focus mode silence the call, but *not* sent it to voicemail?